# asp.net mvc vs asp.net webforms: how can I make my active-x workable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, activex

I have to put active-x object into asp.net mvc view

```
<object classid="activex-site-path/my.dll#myobject" width="288" height="72"> 
</object>
```

but IE doesn't show it (gray box is displayed instead with image icon).
When I put the same lines into asp.net webforms project - active-x appears.

I guess there is something with pathes that are directed to controllers, so I tried to use IgnoreRoute the following way:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("*.dll");
routes.IgnoreRoute("activex-site-path/{*pathInfo}");
```

but it doesn't help.

What is wrong here?

Comment: It tells that dll was downloaded and I can observe it's binary content in Fiddler.

Comment: Have you tried this in another browser? Firebug might give you some more info.